# Handle NFC intents only when preference is set

Tags: android, nfc

I've seen several different apps (like [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) and [NFC TagInfo by NXP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite)) that have an option to autostart (or show up in the "select app" list) when a tag is touched *only if* that option is set in the preferences, and otherwise it seems like the intent filter is totally ignored by the system.

How can this be done in an Android application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Full answer is to use an [`<activity-alias>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html) in the app's manifest, like this:

```
<activity-alias
  android:name=".ActivityAlias"
  android:targetActivity=".YourActualActivity"
  android:enabled="false" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity-alias>
```

`YourActualActivity` is the class for which you want to be able to turn on or off the intent filter. As you do not want to disable the complete activity, you use an activity-alias in which you put the intent filter that you want to enable (here it's disabled by default).

In your PreferenceActivity you set up a listener that is called when the particular setting is changed. It then does something like this:

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
  new ComponentName("your.package.name", "your.package.name.ActivityAlias"),
  changedBooleanPreference ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED :
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
  PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Here `changedBooleanPreference` is the setting that has been changed.

Note that it may take some time before the package manager has made the change effective. It depends on the Android version when and how fast that happens (and perhaps also on the CPU speed of the device).

Comment: This is pretty much the exact same code I ended up with based on CommonsWare's answer, but thanks for posting it anyways, might be a good reference for others :)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the component that has the `<intent-filter>` you wish to have ignored, by using `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`.

Comment: Wow, that was a quick answer, I'll have a look at that, thanks `:)`