# Control NFC feature in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, nfc

My app uses only **one Activity to host multiple fragments**, which means each screen view (page) displayed on the phone is one fragment. The layout of my only activity looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    > 
     <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
      /> 
</merge>
```

As you see above, the `<FrameLayout>` is the fragment placeholder. So, the 1st fragment is added to the placeholder by:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, FirstFragment, TAG1);
```

The next fragment is shown by replace the existing fragment:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, AnotherFragment, TAG2);
```

Everything works fine.

Now, I would like to add one new feature to my app, that's to read NFC tag data and show the data on a fragment (**NfcFragment**).

I followed the Android Developers [NFC guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) & have successfully configured my app to be able to read NFC data. My **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
<application
       …>
        <activity
            android:name="com.nfc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

          </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                        android:resource="@xml/techs" />

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Now, when the phone is close to the NFC Tag, my app is launched automatically. **But** what I need is that, user navigate to the **NfcFragment** manually by user. On **NfcFragment** there is a `ToggleButton` which indicate NFC reader feature **ON** or **OFF**. Only when user has selected **ON**, then if NFC tag is close to phone, the data is read and show on **NfcFragment**. Otherwise, nothing happen.

How to achieve this feature ? Is it possible to implement this feature with my current architecture of **one activity hosting multiple fragments**?

Comment: Are you asking to dynamically trigger the NFC intent based upon an option in your app?

Comment: @ Morrison Chang, Yes. Or alternatively, I would like to handle/control what to launch when a NFC tag is detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically turn on and off the way your app responds to NFC intents, you can use an `<activity-alias>` section in your manifest with the intent filter for NFC intents. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379168/1202968 for the full details.

Answer (score 0):

Look at BroadcastReceiver to handle the NFC intent filter and decide in the onReceive() if your app will handle it or not. See [startActivity() from BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849868/startactivity-from-broadcastreceiver)