# Just read an NFC tag

Tags: android, nfc

I am developing an app that will use NFC tags for identification. All examples I find however, are about starting an app when a certain card is read. I tried looking for an example or documentation on how to do it differently, to no avail.

What I want is:

1. user starts my app
2. user scans NFC card
3. app decides next step

I got some code working now, I just don't get the tag data:

In `onCreate`:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
              getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

tech = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
try {
    tech.addDataType("*/*");
} catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
}
intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] { tech };
```

And in `onResume`:

```
nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, techList);
```

The intent only gets there when the app is active, but the `Intent` I receive is the `PendingIntent` I defined myself, not the `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` intent I want.

Comment: @njzk2 the standard examples, which register an `IntentFilter` in the manifest. And they work, but they don't do what I want. And of course a lot of internet searching.

Comment: apparently you are supposed to register your activity if you want to read nfc. I don't see any method to directly read from it. you can, however, put the handling of the tag in a conditional block that runs only if you are in the position of reading. (not sure what that does if the tag is already in range, though)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found part of the answer here: [NFC broadcastreceiver problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685946/nfc-broadcastreceiver-problem)

That solution doesn't provide a complete working example, so I tried a little extra. To help future visitors, I'll post my solution. It is a `NfcActivity` which subclasses `Activity`, if you subclass this `NfcActivity`, all you have to do is implement its `NfcRead` method, and you're good to go:

```
public abstract class NfcActivity extends Activity  {
    // NFC handling stuff
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {        
        super.onResume();

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

         nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
         nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    // does nothing, has to be overridden in child classes
    public abstract void NfcRead(Intent intent);

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            NfcRead(intent);            
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want that the user first starts your app and only then scans an NFC card, I would recommend using [NFC foreground dispatch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch). In that way, your Activity does not need to have any intent filters in the manifest (and thus will never be called by accident when the user scans another NFC card).
With foreground dispatch enabled, your Activity can receive all NFC intents directly (without any app chooser pop-ups) and decide what to do with it (e.g. pass it on to another Activity).

Comment: Yes, I found some things that do that. Problem I have now is that the `Intent` works fine (I receive it when my `Activity` is active, and it won't start the app from the home screen), I just don't get any NFC data.

Comment: What "NFC data" do you mean? A `Tag` object or an `NdefMessage`?

Comment: a `Tag` object. But I found it now. I had overridden the `OnNewIntent` method, but for some reason it didn't get called. I changed the filters and techlist to `null` and it now works.